# What is the largest function whose integral still converges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

Let C be the set of all functions $f(x)$ whose integral converges, i.e. for some constant $x_0$:

$$\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x) dx < \infty$$

While playing with integrals in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), I noticed the following pattern:

$$\frac{1}{x} \notin C \hspace{2cm} \frac{1}{x^2} \in C$$

$$\frac{1}{x \cdot \ln x} \notin C \hspace{2cm} \frac{1}{x \cdot \ln^2 x} \in C$$

$$\frac{1}{x \cdot \ln x \cdot \ln \ln x} \notin C \hspace{2cm} \frac{1}{x \cdot \ln x \cdot \ln^2 \ln x} \in C$$

Note that the functions at the left become asymptotically smaller, the functions on the right become asymptotically larger, and the gap between them becomes "narrower".

This raises the following question: what is the "largest function" in $C$ and what is the "smallest function" not in $C$?

Formally:

- Is there a function $f_{max}\in C$ such that, for every other function $g\in C$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x) \over f_{max}(x)}=0$$

- Is there a function $f_{min}\notin C$ such that, for every other function $g\notin C$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{f_{min}(x) \over g(x)}=0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for the same reason that the result doesn't work for functions (just define an antiderivative, and so on).

The result for functions is discussed [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196691/is-there-a-slowest-divergent-function).

Similarly for series and sequences, basically by using the integral test.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition this certainly can not be true. If $f_{max}\in C$ then so is $a(f_{max})$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$. But even if you fix that problem I'm pretty sure such a function can't exist.